# Handling exceptions inside Observable.fromCallable() when subscription gets cleared

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a situation where a long running process is wrapped in an `Observable.fromCallable()`. This process is an `OkHttp` call and, if terminated, will throw an `IOException`. If the observable is subscribed to, then the disposable is stored in a `CompositeDisposable` and the exception is handled as expected. However, my code will clear the `CompositeDisposable` in some cases, triggering the `OkHttp` thread termination with no error handling, causing the app to crash with an unhandled exception. Here's a simple unit test example of this problem:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    Observable<Object> o = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("sleeping - this sleep will be interrupted when compositeDisposable gets cleared");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            return null;
        }
    });
    compositeDisposable.add(o.subscribeOn(new IoScheduler()).subscribe());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    compositeDisposable.clear();
}
```

Is there any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike RxJava1, RxJava2  will not deliver this Exception to the Subscriber `onError()`, as you called `cancel()` to unsubscribe and don't wan't to get notifications anymore, so this kind of Exceptions which happens with the unsubscription code go by default now to `Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException()`.

You can either wrap with try catch this kind of exceptions that may happens with cancel, or override the default behavior with:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(Functions.<Throwable>emptyConsumer());
```

or any other handling you would like.

You should also read the [full explanation by akarnokd](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5083) at RxJava github.
Also refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4863) for the above mentioned solutions.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you very much. And thanks for the links, I have not seen the part about the undelivered exceptions before, but it makes perfect sense now.